# How to make an include "Private"?

Tags: c++, class, header, include

Is there any way I can include a file in a class so it can use it but not allow anything including that class into the scope to be able to use it? To simplify lets say I have the iostream header in a class called IO and I make IO be able to write things with the cout function but not let anything that includes IO to be able to use anything in the iostream header. That's not what I want to do but I need to figure this out so I don't "double define" things.

Comment: If you `#include` a file in your source file (.cpp), this will not be seen by any other file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution to that problem is to declare IO in a separate header/source file pair. In the header you forward declare the classes you will be needing and in the source file you include the header you need. This way the actual contents of the header are only accessible in the source file.

Comment: This is not possible if your includes contain types you use as member variables in your class. At compile-time the size of the class, and thus of it's members, need to be known. Forward declarations are only possible for pointer types, not for primitives, macros, or more complex types. Furthermore I have classes that use dozens of said types, so even if I converted them to pointers, it would still be a major chore to maintain dozens of forward declarations rather than a few includes. So I'm still looking for a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, just include it in the `cpp` not in the `h`.

```
// IO.h
// note the lack of #include <iostream>

class IO
{
     // IO stuff...
     void f();
};
```

Then on the `cpp`:

```
// IO.cpp
#include "IO.h"
#include <iostream>

IO::void f()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << '\n';
}
```

When you include `IO.h` in some other file  you're not including `<iostream>`, take a look to the [compilation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) concept.

Comment: What if the header file needs a complete implementation of a specific type like when using std::vector? Even forward declarations won't work in this case.

Comment: @MEMOGAMER000 in that case, the only workaround I know is the PIMPL idiom.